Clarification on "circularity" in definition of a Directed Graphical Model
I'm studying the definition of a directed graphical model (DGM), where we first define a DGM as:
Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with $V = \{1, \dots, n\}$. A directed graphical model (DGM), also known as a Bayesian network, is a family of distributions over $X_V$ defined as follows:
$$
L(G) \triangleq \{ p \text{ is a distribution over } X_V : \exists \text{ legal factors } f_i \text{'s}
$$
$$
\text{s.t. } p(x_V) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i | x_{\pi_i}) \, \forall x_V \} 
$$
Then using the leaf-plucking property, we show that the definition above is equivalent to the one below:

A DGM on a graph $G$ is the set of distributions $p(x)$ that factorizes according to $G$, denoted $p(x) \in $ $L(G)$, if:
$$p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i | x_{\pi_i})$$
where $x_{\pi_i}$ represents the parents of $x_i$ in the graph $G$.

In other words, we show that the factors in the first definition must be the conditional probabilities defined from the joint. But why go through all this trouble, why didn’t we start with this second definition directly? According to my class notes,

the reason is that without the proof [using the leaf-plucking property of DGMs], we would not know whether our definition makes sense, as this definition is circular. Indeed, the conditional $p(x_i | x_{\pi_i})$ is defined from the joint $p(x)$. So we are not allowed (normally) to define a joint by multiplying its conditionals (as you might get no distribution that satisfies this property).

However, I'm struggling to see the circularity here. As I understand it, if we obtain the conditionals $p(x_i | x_{\pi_i})$ from a known joint distribution, but the product of these conditionals does not match the joint distribution, then it would simply imply that this joint distribution is not a member of this DGM (i.e., it doesn’t satisfy the factorization specified by the graph $G$). I think we're only using this factorization as a criterion to identify valid distributions in $L(G)$, not as a construction method for the joint distribution.
Can someone clarify why this definition is considered circular and whether this concern is valid?

In the general sense the joint conceptually precedes thus defines the conditionals as your reference rightly points out, and in a DGM we usually say the joint is represented by the conditionals which could be verified by the leaf-plucking property of DGMs recursively which may seem trivial or acting as a definitional criterion to you.
In the undirected Markov random field case, this may not be trivial since each factor as maximal clique is not conditional probability at all, but non-constant potential, and there's no leaf-plucking property here any more.
